# Wicket: creating markup for listview that presents data from left to righ then once full begins new line

Tags: listview, wicket

so there is me thinking I have it easy coding what i love best when someone asks for this to be done which to my astonishment I have never tackled before.

I have a list of data that i have fed into a listview; easy.

I need to get the list view to present data from left to right of my page and then when it has printed 4 pieces of data i need it to start a  new line and repeat this process in the markup.

any ideas on how to make this trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a HTML and CSS question than Wicket. Make a normal listView, normal HTML for example:

```
<div wicket:id="listView">
  <div wicket:id="listViewItem"></div>
</div>

   add(new ListView<Entity>("listView", list) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Entity> item) {
       item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("listViewItem", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "property")));
    }           
   });
```

Then make in CSS the listView for example 1000px width and listViewItem 250px width and float them. Or any other approach in html/css that would give the same result. Ne need here for Wicket to do something special.

Comment: going to accept this on the basis that i can ensure only 4 are presented per row through css, obviously suffered from brain meltdowns when asking this. thanks :)